# is it possible to determine if an HTTP request to the server originated from Ajax, or clicking a link

Tags: javascript, server, client

From the server, is it possible to identify requests the originate from AJAX calls, or from a *form* that uses `GET` and differentiate them from the user simply clicking on a link?

We have a client-server architecture so I am trying to test whether the above can be determined.

Comment: I don't think you can, a GET is a GET

Comment: Re-phrased question and reduced wording in the title. While it seems like a silly question, OP deserves a documented answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest thing to do in my opinion is you include an additional parameter that indicates that this is from Ajax.

For example pass in the query string something like

```
example.com/blabla.php?ajax=true&input1=username&input2=password
```

And then in your back-end, you check first if it is a Get request.

After that, you check if the parameter **`ajax`** exists and has the value **`true`**.

If it existed you know that it's from Ajax, otherwise it was from another source.
This is the way I normally follow during my development.